# Enabling Mouse Navigation on KDE without GUI

Tags: kubuntu, mouse, kde, plasma

I'm looking for a way to enable mouse navigation on Kubuntu with KDE/Plasma 5.14.3. There used to be a setting for it to enable in the Mouse settings but my Mouse settings no longer have the option with the newer Plasma.[image]

Would there be a way to activate this via terminal?

Thanks.

Comment: The 'Keyboard Navigation' setting can be enabled with the evdev: https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=289&t=153755#p405711

Comment: @user26687 Unfortunately, editing the xorg.conf file did not bring the advanced tab back for me but I did edit the ~/.config/kaccessrc and set the MouseKeys variable to true as shown in that link. This enabled it for me. If you provide this as an answer I will accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if my answer applies to your specific version of plasma, assuming of course that you are still using the same version a year and a half later.

**Graphical Answer**

In newer versions of Plasma the 'Keyboard Navigation' tab appears to be under 'Accessiblity', not 'Input Devices'. It is now called 'Mouse Navigation'
[image: KDE Systems Settings Dialog shows Keyboard Navigation under Accessibility]

**Text-based Answer**

You can turn on Mouse Navigation from the shell using the following command:

```
kwriteconfig5 --file ~/.config/kaccessrc --group Mouse --key MouseKeys --type bool true
```

or by editing the `~/.config/kaccessrc` file manually, as you did, to set `MouseKeys` to `true`.

This will enable keyboard control of the mouse when you next log in. If you want it enabled without having to log out, run the following command, which takes 5–10 seconds on my system:

```
kquitapp5 plasmashell && kstart5 plasmashell &
```

The final `&` is important as it starts the process in the background and you won't kill the plasmashell if you close the terminal emulator you used to run the command.

The `kquitapp5 ...` command was given to me in answer to [a question](https://askubuntu.com/a/1259733/247862) I asked about a similar topic.

Comment: I also found that pressing the shortcut ctrl+shift+num lock will enable keyboard navigation on Plasma 5.19.

Comment: ctrl+shift+num lock has the same behaviour as simply pressing num lock on my Plasma system. If you know how to enable this key combination could you please submit an answer to my related question: [Toggle Keyboard Navigation (aka Mouse Navigation) using keyboard](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1261660/toggle-keyboard-navigation-aka-mouse-navigation-using-keyboard).

Answer (score 2):

[image]

An other solution depending on your kde version